# How to git clone the `.git` directory only?

Tags: git

Is it possible to just clone the `.git` based on ssh or https, so that I can `rm` the `.git` of the current project, replace with another one with different history easily?

Comment: That's called a bare repository. Just use `git clone --bare`.

Comment: Seems like a strange use-case, but if you want to "generate" a repository based off a `.git` folder, why don't you just put the `.git` folder into an empty folder and just `git checkout .`?

Comment: Your question, worded as it is, looks like an awkward way to implement something, which is not described in this question. Would you care to explain what you are trying to achieve ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, do a bare clone with `git clone --bare`. The files normally in the `.git` directory will appear in the cloned directory.

You're not saving yourself any bandwidth by doing this. You have to download all the content anyway when you clone, even a bare clone.